# Legend of Zelda: Can eating Dubious Food hurt you?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild, the description for "Dubious Food" says "Eating it won't hurt you, though....probably". I don't think I've ever been hurt by eating it and I've eaten maybe 15 of them. Given that it gives you a full heart, which is quite a lot given that you can make it from just a single common monster part and makes it ideal for cheaply replenishing yourself. Does anyone have any experience where eating it has hurt your character?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this page](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Dubious_Food), no, eating Dubious Food has no ill effects.

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't say it has no ill effects, it just says it won't hurt him. But given that is says probably I was wondering if eventually it will.  I think I asked a reasonable question, so why mode me down?

Comment: The game's been out for months. If it had any ill effects, it'd be common knowledge by now. Since nothing's mentioned on that page, it has no ill effects.

Comment: @deltaray I am one of those that downvoted your question, due to a lack of research effort on your part.  We expect askers to search first.  That search is not limited to only SE, or the specific site you're asking your question.  Since this game has been out for months, this information is going to be rather easily found, demonstrating the lack of effort on your part.

Comment: I can confirm anecdotally that dubious food, rock hard food, etc. has no ill effects. I don't think its possible to cook anything in BotW that is bad for you, though dubious food is arguably less useful than whatever ingredients you used to make it.

Comment: @deltaray. There's nothing wrong with starting a game late. However, Breath of the Wild is a game that sold over 1 million copies in its first month and almost 5 million copies since release. If dubious food could hurt you, one of those millions of players would've said something about it by now, don't you think? It's not like dubious food is hard to make. Most people will produce some when trying to brew potions, after all. That's what people mean by "lack of research effort".

Comment: @deltaray your rudeness is unnecessary and does not help you make your point whatsoever. If you know how SE works as well as you claim to, you should know one of the core tenets is Be Nice, which your comments certainly were not.

Comment: I don't think I'm being rude. Frank says he downvoted me because I didn't search first. I did search first. Nobody else seems to be really asking this question on the Internet, which surprised the heck out of me so I asked it here. Simply stating that eating it obviously it doesn't cause problems since the game is old otherwise people would have already brought it up is short sighted. There are plenty of things in the world that go undiscovered until someone discovers them and reports on them, such as security bugs in popular software that go undiscovered for years.

Comment: Maybe it hurts you if that's all you eat or something.  The gameplay seems unbalanced if you can just use a simple common item to make food that gives you a whole heart.

Comment: Although there is often hints of additional bonus effects of certain foods and recipes in the item's description. In the case of dubious food and rock hard food, the "it won't hurt you... probably" is just humorous flavour text. No Link of mine or anyone else's to my knowledge has lost health or suffered from eating either (besides his eating animation...).